# Diagonal of a convex polygon such that the obtained cuts have simmilar areas

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry, polygons

Let $P$ be a convex polygon represented with a list of vertices specified by some orientation. Consider the following problem

> **Problem.** Find in linear time a diagonal of $P$ such that the absolute difference of the areas of the obtained polygons is as small as possible.

It is easy to solve the problem if one knows through which vertex must the diagonal pass but I do not see if this sub-problem is solvable in linear time.

Anyone happens to see a linear time algorithm for the stated problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some diagonal $AB$ and alternate between moving $A$ along the boundary until the difference between the diagonals switches sign and doing the same with $B$ in the same direction. When they've both completed one revolution, you've spent linear time and you must have encountered the desired diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain it a bit further? I don't quite understand why this algorithm works properly and what is its key idea.

Comment: @Jernej: The desired diagonal must be such that reducing the larger part (by moving either point) switches the sign of the difference (else it would reduce the absolute difference). The algorithm traverses all diagonals with this property, since for each point there is exactly one pair of opposite points between which the sign changes, and the algorithm finds that pair for each point.